# two select functions in datagrid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagrid

i have a datagrid which bind to SQL database. i would like to use 'select' command in datagrid to perform SQL. I would like to insert two 'select' commands to perform different SQL queries which is 'confirm' and 'rejected' How should I do that?
This is my first query

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.SelectedIndexChanged
    conn.Open()
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand
    cm.CommandText = "UPDATE book SET status = 'confirm' WHERE idnum = '" & DataGrid1.SelectedItem.Cells(8).Text & "'"
    cm.Connection = conn
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

and my second query is

```
conn.Open()
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand
    cm.CommandText = "UPDATE book SET status = 'rejected' WHERE idnum = '" & DataGrid1.SelectedItem.Cells(8).Text & "'"
    cm.Connection = conn
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

Comment: i want two select statements which have different queries

Comment: the first select statement will update status to confirm while the other query will set to rejected. so how to differentiate if the user click select statement

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare another variable as sql command

Comment: Kindly include an explanation to your answer so OP can see where she went wrong.